# Is there a way to rotate a video in VLC (with or without saving) on Mac?

Tags: video, vlc

If I ask Google, I get a solution for Windows (Tools > Effects > Transform). After some searching, I've found an equivalent on Mac: Preferences > Show all > Video > Filters > Rotate or Transformation. However, neither the rotate nor the transformation filters work for me, the video continues playing as it was (in my case 90 degrees rotated). Any idea what I might be doing incorrectly?

Do I maybe need to restart VLC or to reload the video after applying the filter? I have already found checkboxes under Filters, but they don't seem to make any difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I managed to find an answer. Indeed, the VLC has to be restarted (quit and reopen the video file) after applying the correct tranformation filter. In my case, "Rotate by 270 degrees" has resulted in the correct video orientation.

So, if the video is rotated when opening normally:

- Preferences > Show all
- Video > Filters: check "Video tranformation filter"
- Video > Filters > Transformation: set Transform type to "Rotate by 270 degrees" or something else
- Save
- Quit VLC and reopen the file

Hope this helps those who search for the same solution and only find the way of working for Windows.

Comment: That's normal for VLC if you change a pref. It doesn't kick in until you re-launch.